# How to enable SSL mail setting in Framework 4.0

Tags: web-applications, frameworks, ssl, .net-4.0, smtp

I want to enable SSL in the web.config for my framework 4 app however I cant find an example of it.

I see the reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.configuration.smtpnetworkelement.enablessl%28VS.100%29.aspx, however I'm still at a loss.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to install an SSL cert or do you want to redirect users to HTTPS when using your site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. From the content of the link and "smtp" tag I assume you are trying to enable SSL for the SMTP interactions from your web application.
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164242.aspx has example of the smtp configuration settings (equivalent to the programmatic settings that your link was pointing to).
2. In the (unlikely) case, you are trying to setup SSL for the web application itself, that would be web server setting scoped to the website.
3. One SSL setting you can control from web.config (for IIS 7.0 and above) is the SSL requirement policy. To learn about setting up  SSL policy for the web application running on IIS 7.0 and above, look up system.webServer/security/access information in the configuration reference of www.iis.net (I'm not allowed to post more than one hyperlink a time so I cannot type the hyperlink for you)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164242.aspx <- this is what I've been looking for. Thanks.